# What is Penny referencing when she touches her nose?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

Penny touches her nose. What is the significance of that gesture?

Youtube Link for this short clip is

Comment: A similar question was asked in the English SE: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41185/what-does-the-gesture-to-touch-the-side-of-your-nose-with-a-forefinger-mean

Comment: "The question is in the title"? Seriously? Plus a link to a YT video instead of embedding it (yes, that can be done with shorts). And you didn't even bother to google "tapping your nose", which brings up the explanation immediately.

Comment: @BCdotWEB: off-topic maybe but (even reading the "help" section) 1. I can't see how one can embed a video (did try with the usual \[\]\(\) or the link formatting starting with a ' ! '. 2. Is/Isn't it worth editing the OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taping your nose twice means you are right, usually in the sense of guessing correctly. In this scene, Sheldon says Penny is using sarcasm, and she just acknowledged (ie. "*you had some nose*")

A quick search will give you a full [book of answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=tap+on+your+nose&oq=tap+on+your+nose) depending on the culture.